# My 4 GB Micro SD shows only 30 MB total space and I am unable to format it

Tags: windows, sd-card

My 4 GB Micro SD shows only 30 MB total space and I am unable to format it.
I am unable to see any file.
When I attempt to format my card it shows windows is unable to format. Help would be appreciated, as I have important files on this card.

Comment: If you format your card you will lose all your important information; better to copy it first before you try to format it.

Comment: have you checked the security on the SD card. Might that be write protected. Please endure the SD card have READ WRITE DELETE